# Search with array in firebase realtime database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is there any way to search with array in realtime database as cloud database provides us.
Cloud example:

```
.collection("bids")
.where("title", "array-contains-any", ["xx", "yy", "zz"])
```

In above query I got all bids where title is **xx**, **yy**, **zz**.
How do we can search like this in firebase realtime database.

Comment: Yes, I work for me, and Thanks to help me

Answer (score 3):

Actually in real-time database there is no any thing like "array-contains". There for if you have an array you have to deal with just like a regular JavaScript array.

In your case you can try this.

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref('/bids/title');
ref.once('value').then(function(snap) {
  var array = snap.val();
  for (var i in array) {
    var value = array[i]
    console.log(value);
    if (value == 'xx') { ... }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no equivalent operation in the Realtime Database.

The common approach for this type of use-case, is to set up an additional data structure mapping from bid titles to bids as shown here: [Firebase query if child of child contains a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656589/firebase-query-if-child-of-child-contains-a-value)

You can then read the bid IDs for each title with a separate query, look up the additional properties for each bid with another call, and then merge all results in your client-side application code. This is not nearly as slow as you may initially expect, as Firebase [pipelines the requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35931526/speed-up-fetching-posts-for-my-social-network-app-by-using-query-instead-of-obse/35932786#35932786) over a single websocket connection.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays, in Firebase's real-time database, you don't have to do that anymore! These ugly codes to save arrays nowadays are left behind, try to use the module: **[Fireray](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fireray)**.

These codes make Firebase references very ugly, for example:

```json
"dir": {
  "arrays": {
    "users": {
       "0": {},
       "1": {},
       "2": {}
    }
  },
  "others": {}
}
```

It is a Brazilian module, but there is a documentation in English. Give her a chance, she's really very good!

## Links:

- **[Npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fireray)**
- **[Documentation in English](https://github.com/lucasFelixSilveira/FIreray/blob/main/FIreray/assets/ENGLISH.md)**
- **[Repository](https://github.com/lucasFelixSilveira/FIreray)**
- **[Programmer](https://github.com/lucasFelixSilveira)**

Sincerely: Lucas